# Bootstrap Components Doesn't Work In Architect UI Template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a free template called [Architect UI](https://architectui.com/) for my project. They offer me built-in bootstrap components so I don't have to require it. The problem came when I'm using Datatables and Jquery (it doesn't compile).

I tried to require Bootstrap and Jquery manually by CDN, luckily, Datatables is running but some other bootstrap components can't react (like Dropdown and Collapse). When I remove the script of the theme's javascript, it works, but the custom function absolutely can't be used.

I tried some ways, like put JQuery on top of Bootstrap, switching the Bootstrap with main.js position. It looks like when I use both, CDN's Bootstrap and Architect UI's Bootstrap are mixed and messed with each other.

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: The collapse of bootstrap is very sensitive specialy when you are having different jquery action, so it might have a conflict. You should try to make it with jquery or js and see if problem still happen

Comment: @MaxiGui, I made a custom button to trigger the dropdown with jQuery $().dropdown('toggle'), it works on open, but it can't be closed by clicking the button.

Comment: @MaxiGui Oh now the dropdown is work, I just make a function in jQuery by "toggleClass show" the dropdown. I'll try on the Collapse